# JBoss 6: Stop hotdeploy

Tags: java, jboss6.x, hotdeploy

Is it possible to stop the hot deployment from JBoss 6 programmatically? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JNDI name for the Deployment Scanner MBean is:

*jboss.deployment:type=DeploymentScanner,flavor=URL*.

With a lookup with JNDI is possible to access many methods, including the stop() method.